# Stop audio element opening in new window

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, html, audio, streaming

I have a problem with a small audio player project I am working on in rails. I followed the tutorial here http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/create-a-simple-music-streaming-app-with-ruby-on-rails--net-18437 and managed to get the upload, download,delete functionality working fine. I am trying to expand the streaming audio feature with dynamic playlist functionality, using tracks uploaded to my Amazon s3 bucket. At the moment the streaming option loads the audio into the player but doesn't automatically start playback. I would like trigger playback automatically with a single click on the song title in the playlist. 
I have included some commented out code that I was trying in the application.js (triggerPlay function) but each time I try to use the play() method to start playback automatically the player opens in a new window, center screen and a black background, not in the audio player on the index page itself where I would like it.
Sorry if there is something simple I am missing. Any help much appreciated!

Here is the core code.

Index.html

```
<table>
<% @songs.each do |song| %>
<tr>
    <td><%= song.key %></td>
    <td><%= link_to "Delete",  "songs/delete/?song=" + song.key, :confirm => 
    'Are you sure you want      to delete ' + song.key + '?' %></td>
    <td><%= link_to "Download", download_url_for(song.key) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to "Torrent", torrent_url_for(song.key) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to "HTML5 Audio", download_url_for(song.key), :class => "html5" %></td>
</tr>
<% end %>
</table>


<!-- HTML5 section element to hold audio player -->
<section id="audio">
<audio id="player" controls></audio>
</section>
```

application.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var audioSection = $('section#audio');
$('a.html5').click(function() {
var url = $(this).attr('href');

    var audio = $('<audio>', {
         controls : 'controls'
         //autoplay: 'autoplay'
    });

    //var player = document.getElementById('player')

    $('<source>').attr('src', url).appendTo(audio);
    audioSection.html(audio);
    //triggerPlay();
    return false;

});
/*var triggerPlay = function() {
    var player = document.getElementById('player');
    player.play();
}*/
});
```

UPDATE:

I eventually managed to fix the main problem of the audio player loading in a new window. I removed the  audio HTML element that was being constructed inside the Javascript code in the tutorial and replaced it with a var to store a reference to the audio tag instance on the page. Wish I'd spotted that one sooner! Then I just appended to that and the play() function call worked fine. Still need to add ability to dynamically switch tracks without page reload, so any ideas on how this can be improved are welcome!Here is the updated js.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var audioSection = $('section#audio');
  $('a.html5').click(function() {
  var url = $(this).attr('href');

    var player = document.getElementById('player')

    $('<source>').attr('src', url).appendTo(player);
    audioSection.html(player);
    player.play();
    return false;

  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert on the subject, but in your code I notice this bit in specific:

```
<%= link_to "HTML5 Audio", download_url_for(song.key),
```

So to me it seems that, when you click the link, the Javascript does indeed execute as part of the onClick event, but the href of the link is set to the link of the actual mp3 file, meaning that file then opens from the href of the link. Try setting the href of the link to nothing and try again.